# Dwolla MassPay get data for each user?

Tags: dwolla

Its not clear from Dwolla's API if there is a way to get info **for each** user's failed vs. succeeded payment using Dwolla's `MassPayCreate()` or `MassPayDetails()` API calls?

Both API calls seem to report the aggregated data which seems confusing because I'd expect `MassPayDetails()` to return an array of data that could be parsed to get transaction details for each user.

What's the deal with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've extended the [JobByID()](http://developers.dwolla.com/dev/docs/labs/masspay/byid) API call to accept an "include_details" parameter, which when specified True, returns the job's rows and their details.

Additionally, I've added another API call, [RowByID()](http://developers.dwolla.com/dev/docs/labs/masspay/rowbyid), which accepts a job row ID, and returns detailed information for the specified row only.